# Checking for uninitialized DateTime properties?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a class that has numerous properties, two of which are dates:

```cs
public class AchFile
{
    public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    // other properties

    public int Insert()
    {
        //Set file date
        if (FileDate == null)
        {
            FileDate = DateTime.Today;
        }

        //Set effective date
        if (EffectiveDate == null)
        {
            EffectiveDate = ServiceUtil.NextBusinessDay(InterfaceId, FileDate);
        }
            
        return //....
    }
}
```

When I make an instance of the class, I'm not defining `EffectiveDate` or `FileDate`. This causes an issue if I call on `.Insert()` since `DateTime` objects cannot be `null` and therefore, those `if` statements won't be accessed properly.

What would be the best way to update the `if` statements?

Would the following make sense?

```cs
// Default value for a DateTime object is MinValue
if (FileDate == FileDate.MinValue)
{
  FileDate = DateTime.Today;
}

if (EffectiveDate == EffectiveDate.MinValue)
{
  EffectiveDate = ServiceUtil.NextBusinessDay(InterfaceId, FileDate);
}
```

Comment: `Would the following make sense?` - why wouldn't it? the only issue I see is that I would access `MinValue` as `DateTime.MinValue` | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=net-6.0

Comment: IMHO it is up to you decide if you want to have a nullable datetime or check if datetime is minvalue there is no correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `DateTime` to `DateTime?` then they can be null, which seems to be the most accurate representation of what you want (a date that can have no value).

Then you change:

```
ServiceUtil.NextBusinessDay(InterfaceId, FileDate);
```

to

```
ServiceUtil.NextBusinessDay(InterfaceId, FileDate.Value);
```

However, if you want to avoid `null`, then the `default(DateTime)` (or just `default` in later C# versions) is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If `DateTime.MinValue` will never be a *normal* value for those properties, you could check them against that. This feels somewhat unpleasant though, as effectively it becomes a magic value.

Another alternative is to make the properties nullable:

```cs
public DateTime? FileDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
```

Then you *can* check them against `null`, which will be the default value.

Note that if you're really only representing dates, then if you're using .NET 6 I'd recommend using the `DateOnly` type to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm actually using Framework 4.6.

The option to make the properties `nullable` makes a lot more sense though. I think that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize properties on creation and do not check at all:

```
public class AchFile
{
    public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }    
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; } 

    public AchFile() { 
      ...
      FileDate = DateTime.Today;
      EffectiveDate = ServiceUtil.NextBusinessDay(InterfaceId, FileDate);
      ...
    }

    // other properties

    public int Insert() {
      ...
            
      return //....
    }
}
```

If it's not a way out (say, you can create `ArchFile` *today*, but start using it *tomorrow*) and you *have to* keep `DateTime`, not `DateTime?`
you can assign some kind of default value to the properties

```
public class AchFile
{
    // 1 Jan 1 as a default value 
    public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }      = DateTime.MinValue;
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
    // other properties

    public int Insert()
    {
        //Set file date
        if (FileDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            FileDate = DateTime.Today;
        }

        //Set effective date
        if (EffectiveDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            EffectiveDate = ServiceUtil.NextBusinessDay(InterfaceId, FileDate);
        }
            
        return //....
    }
}
```